# suggestion required for Regexp Lookaround in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using regexp heavily in my project. I need some suggestions for Test strings:

```
1     string           3.33
      string
      1
      string          -3.33
```

I need to match the 2nd and 3rd lines (means I do not need string which has 3.33 (currency) at the end of the line).
I tried so many variations. The best I got is:

```
^[\s]+.+[^(?!(\d+\.\d+))]$
```

Line 2 matches with this regular expression, but line 3 does not match.

Note: I do care about the beginning or end of the line. So the test lines marked above are with perfect whitespaces.

I use Java as my programming language.

Comment: I think it would help if you indented your sample input four spaces so that StackOverflow preserves formatting. That would help making your question clearer. Also, you can try playing  with a site such as http://regexpal.com/ or http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Comment: I second this, please improve the sample text.

Comment: I am trying to put indentation. Please allow me sometime.

Comment: Here is the best I am able to explain for indentation and test strings: Test String 1: 1 string 3.33
Test String 2: [spaces] string 
Test String 3: [spaces] 1
Test String 4: [spaces] string -3.33

Answer (score 1):

```
[^(?!(\d+\.\d+))]
```

is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).  A character class matches exactly one character from the set of characters you describe within the square brackets.  Yours is equivalent to this:

```
[^!()+.\d]
```

The `^` at the beginning inverts the set, and `\d` matches a digit just like it does outside a character class, but the rest of the characters are matched literally.  In other words, you're telling it to match any one character that's not `!`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `.`, or a digit.

It looks like you were trying to use a negative lookahead, which is a valid approach.  If you only care about the dollar amount at the end of the line, you can do this:

```
^(?!.*\d+\.\d+$).*$
```

The lookahead tries to match `\d+\.\d+` at the end of the line.  If it succeeds, the overall match fails.  Otherwise, the `.*$` consumes the whole line so you can retrieve it with the Matcher's `group()` method.

This assumes you're applying the regex to one line at a time.  If you're trying to find matching lines within a larger text you should specify MULTILINE mode, which you can do like this:

```
(?m)^(?!.*\d+\.\d+$).*$
```

Comment: I guess, this seems to be a good idea. I will try that for sure. I like your explanation. I will keep this in mind for further use. Thank you Alan.

Comment: Alan, the regexp is perfect what I am looking for. I learned something better for negative lookahead. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

did you test the text line by line?

then you may use re: `\d+\.\d+$` to match the text which you do **NOT** need. If match() return false, then you take the line.

well it's like grep -v.

if test it with grep:

```
kent$  cat a
1     string           3.33
      string
      1
      string          -3.33

kent$  grep -Pv '\d+\.\d+$' a
      string
      1
```

Comment: Kent, Actually this is a part of a big program. I can not do it the way you have suggested. Thanks for advice though.